# NetBeans complains, but the code runs

Tags: python, netbeans

I am new to python. I am writing programs in NetBeans.

- NetBeans 8.1
- Python Plugin for NetBeans
- Python 3.5.1
- Plugin is set up for 3.5.1, instead of the default 2.7

NetBeans complains when I write the statement

```
print ("_ ", end='')
```

The error is

```
no viable alternative at input '='
```

It appears that NetBeans is checking for 2.7 syntax, instead of 3.5. I am able to run the code, so NetBeans is using 3.5 to execute.

How do I configure NetBeans so it uses the correct syntax checking?

---

After the recommendation of @alecxe, I reported a bug to NetBeans.

NetBeans does not support python 3.x. The plugin runs the correct version, but the IDE syntax checking is linked to 2.x.

> Thank you for your report. Note that we do not officially support
>   Python 3.x yet. However, It is a high-importance task on our nbPython
>   Jira board... Marking this bug as Duplicate. Suggest you follow
>   [Bug#229940](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229940) for notification.

PS. PyCharm is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is reproducible on my end too. Even if the default Python Environment is set to Python3.5 and the Project Interpreter is also set to Python3.5, it still uses Python2 specific syntax checks. For example, it does not highlight the `print` if it is used as a statement and not function:

[image]

I don't think this particular behavior is configurable and **this is a bug** (I suspect the bundled Jython is used for the "live" syntax checking). You should definitely file an issue [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=NEW&bug_status=STARTED&bug_status=REOPENED&list_id=648030&order=changeddate%20DESC%2Cbug_status%2Cpriority%2Cassigned_to%2Cbug_id&product=python&query_based_on=&query_format=advanced).

---

External tools like `PyLint` might help, but it is [not yet integrated](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=161404).

---

<sup>And, just saying, PyCharm has a completely free community edition.</sup>

Comment: I have submitted a bug report.